# Doxygen creates empty image titles for Docbook output

Tags: image, doxygen, docbook

I'm using doxygen 1.8.14 to create docbook output. Images are marked up with

```
\image docbook Legend.png "Coloring and Graph Scheme" width=10cm
```

The resulting docbook is

```
<figure>
    <title></title>
    <mediaobject>
        <imageobject>
            <imagedata width="10cm" align="center" valign="middle"
             scalefit="1" fileref="Legend.png"></imagedata>
        </imageobject>
    <caption>Coloring and Graph Scheme</caption>
    </mediaobject>
</figure>
```

Note how the `<title>` is empty (the title string from markup went to the `<caption>` element).
This causes the document's "List of figures" section to look like this:

```
1.1. ........................... 8
1.2. ........................... 9
2.1. .......................... 13
2.2. .......................... 14
2.3. .......................... 16
```

(because the List of Figures uses the figure **`<title>`** contents, not the `<caption>` content). Before I start hacking or whacking the caption to the title with a perl one-liner, is there something I have overlooked? In the doxygen configuration perhaps?

The correct docbook code is

```
<figure>
    <title>Coloring and Graph Scheme</title>
    <mediaobject>
        <imageobject>
            <imagedata width="10cm" align="center" valign="middle"
             scalefit="1" fileref="Legend.png"></imagedata>
        </imageobject>
    </mediaobject>
</figure>
```

Comment: Although the docbook handling has been greatly rewritten in the current master version of doxygen, I see here also the same problem. What docbook tag has to be used to get it in the table of content?

Comment: Or better formulated how should the section look like?

Comment: @albert The correct tag to use is `<title>`. A caption is a longer explanation about what an image depicts. In scientific journals you often see captions of many lines. Docbook/XSL-FO also puts the title above or below a figure, depending on what you have in the style sheet customization layer.

Comment: In the master version it is on the wrong place as well (inside the mediaobject), I'll have to dive into the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 1.8.14 the title is written as a caption, in the master version til now the title is written, but on the wrong place. For this I made a proposed pull request for doxygen (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/6638).

A workaround is to use:

```
\docbookonly
<figure>
    <title>Coloring and Graph Scheme</title>
    <mediaobject>
        <imageobject>
            <imagedata width="10cm" align="center" valign="middle"
             scalefit="1" fileref="Legend.png"></imagedata>
        </imageobject>
    </mediaobject>
</figure>
\enddocbookonly
```

instead of:

```
\image docbook Legend.png "Coloring and Graph Scheme" width=10cm
```

EDIT: Code of pull request has been integrated in master on github.

Comment: Thank you, that was quick! I hope Dimitry gets around to the first update this year :-)

Comment: As far as I know he plans to make a release between Christmas and New Year (this year)